# Firefox 48 is not opening the any URL in the script after using selenium web driver 3.0

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, eclipse-neon

i have updated the selenium webdriver version to 3.0 beta after that i generated a script in eclipse ide. after i run the script Firefox is opened but not redirecting to the url.

this is the simple code generated by selenium ide

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Selenium {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private boolean acceptNextAlert = true;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();

  @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "https://www.google.co.in/";
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  }

  @Test
  public void testF() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl + "/?gws_rd=ssl");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("hi");
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("hifi");
  }

  @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }

  private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
    try {
      driver.switchTo().alert();
      return true;
    } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private String closeAlertAndGetItsText() {
    try {
      Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
      String alertText = alert.getText();
      if (acceptNextAlert) {
        alert.accept();
      } else {
        alert.dismiss();
      }
      return alertText;
    } finally {
      acceptNextAlert = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you add more information about your error ? Did you configure gecko driver (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium)?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of capability issues, Just like the other drivers available to Selenium from other browser vendors, [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette/WebDriver) has released an executable call geckodriver that will run alongside the browser.

You need to download latest executable [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and set this downloaded path from your machine as system property to run your test case with Firefox driver as below :

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path/to downloaded/geckodriver.exe");
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
 capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);

 //Now do your further stuff with Firefox driver
```

Answer (score 0):

> To run exported IDE tests, ensure that the leg-rc package is on the
>   classpath.

Which was mentioned in Selenium 3 change log. Please refer [change log](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/master/java/CHANGELOG).