# Getting error xception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I am new to selenium web driver, while compiling a script to open a new browser in MAcOS.. I am getting this error:

```
exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
The path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver.gecko.driver system property; for more information, see https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver. The latest version can be downloaded from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:109)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
  at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:238)
  at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.<init>(FirefoxDriver.java:127)
  at NewPackage.NewClass.main(NewClass.java:93)
```

Please help to resolve this out....

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium#answer-38780809

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail to Launch Mozilla with selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38676719/fail-to-launch-mozilla-with-selenium)

Comment: thanks sudharsan :)

Answer (score 0):

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","path of/geckodriver.exe");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

as suggested by sudharsan I used the above code,since am working in MAcos it started giving me more error,slight variation in above code is we don't need .exe extension while specifing path in MAC...

```
 System.setProperty("`webdriver.gecko.driver","path of/geckodriver");
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(capabilities);
```

This gave me the correct output.