# Whether selenium Standalone server 2.50 not support in Fire fox browser 49.0 version?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Latest mozilla version not supported in selenium, Is there any solution?

here is my code

> ```
> package Admin_Package;
>
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver; import
> org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
>
> public class test {
>
>
>
> public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
>     // Download "geckodriver.exe" from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases
>     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\ecl_ee\\jar_files\\gecko_driver\\geckodriver.exe");
>     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
>
>     driver.get("http://www.facebook.com");
>
>     System.out.println("Application title is ============="+driver.getTitle());
>
>     driver.quit();
> } }
> ```
>
> **If I am using 3.0.1 standalone below mention error is coming** 
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver executable does not exist: D:\ecl_ee\jar_files\gecko_driver\geckodriver.exe
>         at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.checkExecutable(DriverService.java:121)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:116)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService.access$000(GeckoDriverService.java:37)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(GeckoDriverService.java:95)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:296)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.createCommandExecutor(FirefoxDriver.java:277)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:247)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:242)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver.(FirefoxDriver.java:135)
>         at Admin_Package.test.before(test.java:20)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>         at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:823)
>         at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1131)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>         at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:778)
>         at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:632)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
>         at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1225)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1075)
>         at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1047)
>         at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
>         at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)

Browser opened, then after this error is getting

> ```
> 1478585217132 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:42466
> Nov 08, 2016 11:36:57 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
> 1478585217594 mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\Divya\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.Xge4QjcxXLSu
> 1478585217596 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
> 1478585217605 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:2185
> 1478585219168 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2185
> 1478585221536 Marionette  INFO    startBrowser 2a9015b9-cac1-4641-839d-8f9279055519
> Nov 08, 2016 11:37:01 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
> JavaScript warning: http://reventics.infoversity.in/app/services/sharedProperties.js, line 13: unreachable code after return statement
> JavaScript warning: http://reventics.infoversity.in/app/services/sharedProperties.js, line 13: unreachable code after return statement
> Application title is =============Reventics
> [Child 1708] ###!!! ABORT: Aborting on channel error.: file c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w32-00000000000000000000/build/src/ipc/glue/MessageChannel.cpp, line 2052
> Nov 08, 2016 11:37:09 AM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess destroy
> SEVERE: Unable to kill process with PID 6120
> ```

[image]

**Before, After suite class**

> ```
> package Admin_Package;
> import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
> import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
> import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;
> public class BA_Admin {
> public static WebDriver driver;
> @BeforeSuite
> public void beforeSuite() throws InterruptedException {           
> System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","D:\\ecl_ee\\jar_files\\gecko_driver\\geckodriver.exe");
> WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
> driver.get("URL");
> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
> driver.manage().window().maximize();
> }
> @AfterSuite     
> public void afterSuite() throws Exception { 
> driver.quit();
> }
> }
> ```

**Extended class**

> ```
> package Admin_Package;
> import java.util.List;
> import org.openqa.selenium.By;
> import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
> import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
> import org.testng.annotations.Test;
> public class Role_Add extends Admin_Package.BA_Admin{
> @BeforeTest
> public void login() throws InterruptedException {
> driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtUsername']")).sendKeys("venkatm");
> Thread.sleep(5000);
> driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtPassword']")).sendKeys("Password@123");
> Thread.sleep(5000);
> driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]")).click();
> Thread.sleep(5000);
> System.out.println("Login Test Case Passed"); 
> } 
> @Test
> public void link1() throws InterruptedException { 
> driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[1]/aside/section/ul[1]/li[1]")).click();
> Thread.sleep(5000);
> }  
> }
> }
> ```

**After run this class below error is coming**

> ```
> 1478588994124 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:36811
> Nov 08, 2016 12:39:54 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
> 1478588994625 mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path C:\Users\Divya\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.9LNcRBy7LvnX
> 1478588994628 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe
> 1478588994637 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on localhost:3453
> 1478588996301 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 3453
> 1478588998908 Marionette  INFO    startBrowser 533a5574-8667-4d6a-8455-b78be6709d83
> Nov 08, 2016 12:39:59 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
> INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
> JavaScript warning: http://reventics.infoversity.in/app/services/sharedProperties.js, line 13: unreachable code after return statement
> JavaScript warning: http://reventics.infoversity.in/app/services/sharedProperties.js, line 13: unreachable code after return statement
> [Utils] Attempting to create D:\ecl_ee\Projects\Reventics\test-output\Default suite\Default test.html
> [Utils]   Directory D:\ecl_ee\Projects\Reventics\test-output\Default suite exists: true
> [Utils] Attempting to create D:\ecl_ee\Projects\Reventics\test-output\Default suite\Default test.xml
> [Utils]   Directory D:\ecl_ee\Projects\Reventics\test-output\Default suite exists: true
> FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest login
> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at Admin_Package.Role_Add.login(Role_Add.java:18)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:86)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:515)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:216)
> at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:143)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:656)
> at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
> at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1225)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1150)
> at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1075)
> at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1047)
> at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:137)
> at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:58)
>
> SKIPPED CONFIGURATION: @AfterTest Create_Role
> SKIPPED: link1
> ```

Thanks,

Divya

Comment: Yes there is, you should see this question posted :
[Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium)

Comment: @ Bob Reynolds I am using your referring code but, getting same issue browser not supported

Comment: Maybe could you give a trace of your code ?

Comment: @ Bob Reynolds   I am sending my code please once check

Comment: did you try with the latest selenium jars? 3.0.1? or still trying with 2.50?

Comment: @Naveen I am using 2.53

Comment: upgrade to 3.0.1 and try. I don't think so 2.53 have support for geckodriver. From Firefox 48 onwards, you have to use geckodriver. https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

Comment: @Naveen I am updating 3.0.1 jar but, getting error (above mentioned please check)

Comment: the error says "The driver executable does not exist: D:\ecl_ee\jar_files\gecko_driver\geckodriver.exe". did you really keep the geckodriver.exe in the said location?

Comment: Agree with naveen, this clearly is a "File not found" issue! nothing to do with browser support I guess! Is this solved? @Divya

Comment: @Naveen & Wama U R right I am getting wrong path, It's modifying, but I am getting  another error above is mentioned please tell me the solution (browser opened and get the URL, then this error is coming )

Comment: It seems a plugin issue that you installed in the firefox browser. go through all the plugins installed. https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1006356. uninstall or update the plugin which is causing the problem.

Comment: @Naveen I am using extended class but it's failed above is mentioned code please once check

Comment: I did not understand the problem. not much aware of the framework. from the trace, I got to know that NullPointerException is raised "FAILED CONFIGURATION: @BeforeTest login
java.lang.NullPointerException
at Admin_Package.Role_Add.login(Role_Add.java:18)". check what is the reason for the exception. is it because the class run before some other class? or in the login method, element is not found? not so sure.

Comment: @Naveen above mentioned in my code please once check. The same code executed in 45.0.1 firefox version

Comment: Though I am not sure why NullPointerExcpetion is thorwn, I suggest check the folllowing things. 1. whether driver object is NOT null? 2. whether username field is NOT found? 3. whether Password field is NOT found? just use print statement as follows. 1. sysout driver 2. sysout driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtUsername']")) 3. sysout driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='txtPassword']")) and see whether are retuning NullPointer or the objects. same applies to all the elmeents in the login method

Comment: I doubt the following XPATH "driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[2]/div/form/div/div/div[2]/div/button[1]")).click();" please recheck in the browser using Firebug plugin where it matches to any element or not?

Comment: @Naveen All paths are in site, and I am using single class it's working, but when using extended class it's fail

Comment: in the following line "WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();" remove WebDriver reference and try. It seems like you are creating a local variable which is causing all the problems (and you are referencing global driver object which is never initialized).

Comment: @Naveen it's working Thanq so much!!!

Comment: I am glad to hear that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

creating a local variable is causing all the troubles.

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

remove `WebDriver` reference in the object creation, so the reference will be added to the global `driver` object so that Child classes can refer.