# Selenium : I am Using Firefox version 46.01 and Tested in ecllipse Error message displayed

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

Error message displayed as **"org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host 127.0.0.1 on port 7055 after 45000 ms"**

Tried to resolve this issue, but couldn't. Can anyone help me over this?

Currently I am using firefox 46.01 and selenium jar file 2.53.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a [geckodriver](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) with the newest version of Firefox. With earlier versions you had to install an addon, but geckodriver is a part of [Marionette](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/QA/Marionette), which is developed by Mozilla, so no need for that.

Also check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium).

Answer (score 1):

Check your Selenium Version and Your version of FireFox. I think that your current selenium version doesn't support at all that version of FireFox.

[Selenium ChangeLog](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/CHANGELOG)