# Error in selenium code at the time of url access

Tags: selenium, webdriver

At the time of aceess url below error display:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver
>   executable does not exist: C:\geckodriver\geckodriver.exe

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to download geckodriver from the below URL and configure its path in your webdriver. If you could tell us which language you are using, we shall provide you with sample code.

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases

You may also download the windows build for your platform(**geckodriver.exe**) and just copy it to **C:\geckodriver** which is the default path.

Comment: I am using Java language

Comment: @SantoshBisale - If you are not using default location then you need to set System property **webdriver.gecko.driver** as shown in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37785686/how-to-use-the-gecko-executable-with-selenium