# Chromedriver setup in selenium grid 3 node

Tags: selenium, batch-file, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

My **StartSeleniumGridNode.bat** file.

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register ^
-browser "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS" ^
-browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\chromedriver.exe"
```

This is the error i am getting in the console.

```
D:\SeleniumGridPractice>StartSeleniumGridNode.bat
D:\SeleniumGridPractice>java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -ro
le node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,m
axInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2,plat
form=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\c
hromedriver.exe"
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown opti
on: -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=D:\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\chromedriver
.exe
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:282)
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265)
        at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.<init>(JCommander.java:210)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$3.setConfiguration(GridLaunch
erV3.java:267)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.buildLauncher(GridLauncherV3.
java:155)
        at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:75)`

D:\SeleniumGridPractice>
```

NB: **StartSeleniumGridHub.bat** is running perfectly. Also there is no issues with Firefox.

Comment: In the bat file you mentioned about `Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\Vizrt\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\chromedriver.exe"` but your error stacktrace mentions some other location. Can you cross check once? Thanks

Comment: Your error stacktrace mentions about `-Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\c hromedriver.exe"` please check once. Thanks

Comment: Can you take a look to this approach
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43733249

Comment: Sorry my bad. Updated.

Comment: @KaziSafaetMahmudAuvi I am still not sure about your exact requirement. Your subject mentions `Chromedriver setup in selenium grid 3 node` which is the basic step but you are trying to setup a Node with added Capabilities as in `-browser "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS"`. Any reason to avoid the default Capability & settings?

Comment: @Dev Actually I just started learning Grid. So things are not that much clear to me.
So what do you prefer in this case by keeping the capabilities in a json file or else?

Comment: @KaziSafaetMahmudAuvi Well :) you already got an answer Accepted. Let the Question RIP :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please change

`java -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS" -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\chromedriver.exe"`

to

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="D:\SeleniumGridPractice\drivers\chromedriver.exe" -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.4.0.jar -role node -hub http://127.0.0.1:4444/grid/register -browser "browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3,platform=WINDOWS" -browser "browserName=chrome,maxInstances=2,platform=WINDOWS"`

and try again.

**Explanation :**

JVM arguments (the ones that begin with `-D`) are supposed to be provided before `-jar` argument. But since you provided it after `-jar` instead of it being treated as a JVM argument, its being fed as a command line argument to the `selenium-server` standalone jar.

Comment: Thanks @Krishnan da... 
I found the exact solution that you gave. Also thanks for the explanation.